# Что значит "вызов (публичного) метода экземпляра" на концептуальном уровне в объектно-ориентированном программировании?

Tags: node.js, ооп, объекты

Абстрактный получился вопрос, но к сожалению ограничение по количеству символов не позволяет включить в заголовок минимальное пояснение. Скорее всего, правильным ответом будет один из двух вариантов:

1. Приказать экземпляру что-либо сделать
2. Сделать какие-либо действия над экземпляром

Разница такая же, как между непереходными (1-ый вариант) и переходными (2-ой вариант) глаголами.

Года 4 я думал, что первый вариант верен, потому что смысл методов инстанса с точки зрения ООП - инкапсулировать поведение, работающее с данными инстанса (вообще они могут с данными и не работать, но тогда многие интегрированные среды разработки предложат сделать метод статическим).

Типичные примеры типа "Приказать экземпляру что-либо сделать" - `rabbit.jump()` или `car.move()`, то есть мы говорим кролику прыгать, а машине - ехать, при этом как оно там реализовано - мы знать не обязаны.

Однако один из первых примеров из знаменитой книги "Философия Java" Брюса Эккеля показывает использование методов по второму сценарию (если Light действительно в переводе с английского помимо "свет" означат "лампа"). Если кролик может прыгать сам, то лампа сама себя не включит (`light.on()`) и ярче сама себя не сделает (`brighten()`).  Я понимаю, если бы эти методы
были у светильника, где лампа - лишь одна из деталей, но у меня недостаточный уровень владения английском, чтобы заявить, что переводчик ошибся, переводя `light` как "лампочка".

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот задался я этим вопросом спустя годы после чтения этой книги тоже неспроста - я решил обернуть объект `HTTP.Response` из Node.js в объект с более удобным интерфейсом. Типичный пример использования нативного `HTTP.Response`:

```
response.
    writeHead(500, "Internal server error").
    end();
```

То есть для отправки ответа клиенту необходимо вызвать два метода. Метод `end` происходит от поточной сущности объекта `response`, но мне детали его реализации не очень интересны по сравнению с удобством использования, поэтому я решил добавить метод, берущий на себя вызов обоих методов `writeHead` и `end`.

Хотел назвать этот метод `send` или `submit`, но `response.submit()` означает, что запрос должен отправить сам себя. Четно говоря, не знаю, как объект `reponse` там устроен - может он и вправду сам себя отправляет, но всё же насчёт того теоретического момента, о котором идёт речь в данном вопросе, я бы хотел прояснить.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На моем уровне понимания концепции ООП программирования - любой публичный метод экземпляра служит для взаимодействия с данными этого экземпляра.

Цели взаимодействия могут быть самыми разными. От простого извлечения данных до изменения данных или изменения состояния композитных данных или даже отправки сообщений другим объектам системы о том, что был затронут этот экземпляр системы.

Так что, сформулировать ответ на поставленный вопрос односложно не получится.

В хорошо спроектированной системе каждый элемент отвечает за свою часть работы, стараясь не затрагивать другие области данных.

А каким глаголом описать выполняемое действие - это уже на совести программиста.

Может объект сам выполняет действие над другим объектом, а может он изменяет свое свойство, а может он изменяет свойства связанных с ним объектов... Вариантов очень много. ИМХО.

С моей точки зрения - читаемость кода - это очень важный аргумент при проектировании системы. Если решение удовлетворяет этому требованию и не вводит в заблуждение, то название подходящее.

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ!